# How can I prove $(\min_x f(x)) + g(x) \geq \min_x (f(x) + g(x))$?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

How can I prove $(\min_x f(x)) + g(x) \geq \min_x (f(x) + g(x))$? In other words, on the left side we only optimize $x$ with respect to function $f(\cdot)$ while on the right side we do so with respect to summation of both functions $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$?

Comment: You parentheses don’t work out.in the title.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Nope, still wrong. After $\geq$ the parents are in the form $(())()).$

Comment: Sorry, I guess now it's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't necessarily the case: consider $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = (x - 1)^2.$ Evaluating the left side at $x = 1$ yields $\min[x^2] + (1 - 1)^2 = 0 + 0 = 0,$ but the function $x^2 + (x - 1)^2$ is strictly positive in the real numbers, so $\min [x^2 + (x - 1)^2] > 0.$

The reason this doesn't work out is because on the left-hand side we can effectively pick the values of $x$ for $f$ and $g$ separately, so the minimum value we can achieve is $\min [f(x)] + \min[g(x)],$ but on the left-hand side we must use the same value of $x$ for both $f$ and $g,$ so if the minima don't align then we can't get as low.

Comment: Thanks, got it, how about $f(x^*) + g(x^*) \geq f(x^{**}) + g(x^{**}) $ where $x^* = \argmin_x f(x)$ and $x^{**} = \argmin_x f(x) + g(x)$

Comment: Sorry, this sounds like a seperate question. I can ask it separately if you mind?

Comment: I don't mind, it's not that complicated of a question and it's along the same lines so we can just get it sorted pretty quickly. Just suppose that $f(x^*) + g(x^*) < f(x^{**}) + g(x^{**})$ and then show how that yields a contradiction with the definition of $x^{**}.$ (if $x^{**}$ minimizes $f(x) + g(x)$ then there shouldn't be any other $y$ such that $f(y) + g(y)$ is lower)